# Delete all previous lists if a following list contains same element

Tags: python, list

For expample I have some lists:

```
[date1, time1, nickname1, point1 = 56.341708,43.948463]
[date2, time2, nickname2, point2 = 56.321795,43.9996]
[date3, time3, nickname3, point1 = 56.341708,43.948463]
[date4, time4, nickname4, point1 = 56.341708,43.948463]
[date5, time5, nickname5, point3 = 56.236278,43.960233]
[date6, time6, nickname7, point3 = 56.236278,43.960233]
```

I need to delete all previous lists if the following list have the same point.
Correct output should be:

```
[date2, time2, nickname2, point2 = 56.321795,43.9996]
[date4, time4, nickname4, point1 = 56.341708,43.948463]
[date6, time6, nickname7, point3 = 56.236278,43.960233]
```

My code removes some lists but it has the task not fully:

checked3 - list of lists
checked4 - list of points

Code:

```
r = -1
v = -2
k = -len(checked3)
try:
    while v > k:
        if str(checked4[r]) in checked3[v]:
            checked3.pop(v)
            print ('now', checked3)
            v = v - 1
        else:
            print ('else', checked3)
            r = r - 1
except:
    pass
```

Could you help me please, how can I get Correct output?

Comment: I'd try a dictionary better. So you assign values to d['point1'], d['point2'], d['point3'], etc. That way it will overwrite any previous values there.

Comment: Let's say that there's another `point1 = 56.341708,43.948463` at the end of the list.  Do you want to keep it (because the point *immediately* before it was different) or discard it (because we've already seen that point before)?

Comment: Your sample code does not have `checked3` and `checked4` defined. I wonder if you could do an edit.

Comment: Lists don't use `=`.  What exactly is this data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
distinctList = []
distinctDict = {}

for l in checked3:
    point = l[-1] #last element of inside list
    distinctDict[point] = l

for l in distinctDict:
    distinctList.append(distinctDict[l])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

1. Create a dictionary of points.
2. Walk the list from behind( since you want the last value retained)
3. Flag when you find an item's first occurrence
4. Delete when you find a duplicate point

For simplicity in explanation, I simulated with a  list of lists that has strings for the inconsequential fields and tuples for points.

```
listOfLists = [
['date1', 'time1', 'nickname1',  (56.341708,43.948463)],
['date2', 'time2', 'nickname2', (56.321795,43.9996)],
['date3', 'time3', 'nickname3', (56.341708,43.948463)],
['date4', 'time4', 'nickname4', (56.341708,43.948463)],
['date5', 'time5', 'nickname5', (56.236278,43.960233)],
['date6', 'time6', 'nickname7', (56.236278,43.960233)]
]
```

Using dictionary comprehension, create a record for each point

```
pointsDict = {item[3]:'Duplicates in list' for item in listOfLists}
```

Walk the list reversed, from behind. We flag for deleting by altering the value corresponding to the point to set it to 'Can delete'. When we encounter 'Can delete' as a value corresponding to the item in iteration, we delete it from the original list.

```
for item in listOfLists[::-1]:
    point = item[3]
    if pointsDict[point] == 'Duplicates in list':
        pointsDict[point] = 'Can delete'
    elif pointsDict[point] == 'Can delete':
        listOfLists.pop(listOfLists.index(item))
```

At this point listOfLists contains what you want.